# Image magick TIFF layers count always returns 1

Tags: php, imagemagick

update: I have figured out the problem by running a `cat` command in `exec` and reading the image as text and searching for the word `layer`. it works on all the images I tested. It even works if the layer is renamed to something other than `Layer 1`.

```
exec("cat $filename | fgrep -a 'layer'", $ret);
if(!strpos(implode($ret),'layer')){
    $layers='false';
}else{
    $layers='true';
}
```

please vote to close, or whatever happens in this situation.

/////////////////////////////////

Im trying to find out if a tiff file contains a single layer or multiple layers so i can set a true/false value in my database. The problem is no matter what I do it always says the image has one layer.  The more I read, it seems that what I am doing is actually meant to count the number of layers in a GIF file.  Any help would be appreciated

```
$all=exec("/opt/local/bin/identify -format %w-%h-%x-%z-'%[colorspace]'-'%[channels]'-'%[scenes]' $newfile");
$ex=explode("-",$all);
$width=$ex[0];
$height=$ex[1];
$dpi=$ex[2];
$dpi=explode(" ", $dpi);
$dpi=$dpi[0];
$depth=$ex[3];
$colorspace=$ex[4];
$channels=$ex[5];
$layers=$ex[6];
```

All of my variables work correctly except for `$layers`.  it returns `1` no matter how many layers my file has.

Comment: GIF files don't have layers. An animated gif may have multiple frames, but they're not "layers".

Comment: yeah. i believe you are correct.  i would like a layer count of TIF files though, not GIF.

Answer (score 1):

TIFF files don't have multiple 'layers'. But they can contain multiple pages (and I think this is what you mean).

You can use simply

```
 identify  multipage.tiff
```

and you should see a separate line for each single TIFF page image:

```
multipage.tif[0] TIFF 1728x2292 1728x2292+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 220KB 0.010u 0:00.000
multipage.tif[1] TIFF 1728x2292 1728x2292+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 220KB 0.000u 0:00.000
multipage.tif[2] TIFF 1728x2292 1728x2292+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 220KB 0.000u 0:00.000
multipage.tif[3] TIFF 1728x2292 1728x2292+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 220KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Note, that the counting is zero-based and starts with `[0]`.

The `%[scenes]` of your format string in your PHP `exec` also does already query the right thing...